# PHP zip_open and new ZipArchive() causes exit

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have tried this in two different environments, one works one does not. All I am trying to do is open the zip but at the moment I call one of those functions  **zip_open** or **new ZipArchive()** the code brakes, exits without an error. What could be the problem ?

```
$zip = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
file_put_contents($zipfile, $zip);
chmod($zipfile, 0775);

$zip = new ZipArchive(); 
$zip->open($zipfile);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code and describe where exactly is the problem? What have you tried and a proper error message?

Comment: @Danizavtz I add the code block , there is no error, no warrning it just stops working like it exits after $zip = new ZipArchive();

Comment: What php version are you using? What happens when you run the zip command in cmd line shell?

Comment: @Danizavtz php -v : PHP 7.1.30-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 31 2019

Comment: @Danizavtz zip : Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]